How can I add a custom message variable in a Datadog monitor using Terraform?
I want to create a variable so users can add a custom message within the Datadog monitor message section. Just not sure what the best method would be.
Monitor Code:
resource "datadog_monitor" "aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization_monitor_tf" {
  count   = var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.deploy ? 1 : 0
  name    = "${var.unique_prefix} - Aurora PostgreSQL RDS CPU Utilization"
  type    = "query alert"
  query   = "avg(last_${var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.query_time}):avg:aws.rds.cpuutilization{%{~if local.monitor_query_string == ""}*%{else}${local.monitor_query_string}%{endif~}} by {region,dbinstanceidentifier} >= ${var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.critical_threshold}"
  message = <<EOF
RDS CPU Usage is averaging {{value}}, which breached current thresholds {{#is_alert}}{{threshold}}{{/is_alert}}{{#is_warning}}{{warn_threshold}}{{/is_warning}}

Percentage of CPU utilization. Recommended metric for standard monitoring. Available for Aurora DBs.

* __Severity__: {{#is_alert}}**Alert**{{/is_alert}}{{#is_warning}}**Warning**{{/is_warning}}
* __Value__: {{value}}
* __Alert threshold__: {{#is_alert}}{{threshold}}{{/is_alert}}{{#is_warning}}{{warn_threshold}}{{/is_warning}}
* __Last triggered at__: {{last_triggered_at}} ({{last_triggered_at_epoch}})

${local.notification_string}
EOF

  tags                     = local.monitor_tags
  include_tags             = "true"
  notification_preset_name = "hide_handles"
  priority                 = var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.priority_level
  restricted_roles         = var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.restricted_roles
  monitor_thresholds {
    critical = var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.critical_threshold
    warning  = var.aurora_postgres_cpu_utilization.warning_threshold
  }
}


So what exactly is the problem? The code doesn't work as expected? Is there any error?

I want to add a variable at the bottom of the monitor msg, so users can add a custom message. Current code works fine, just wanted to add a feature.

You're already referencing a local variable ${local.notification_string} in the message template, so maybe just add (or replace it with) a variable ${var.myvariable}? Sorry I'm still not sure if I understand your problem.

The want VS need ... for code golf please refer to:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

@RuiJarimba Thank you!! Looks like i was over thinking the issue.

I will be doing what @RuiJarimba recommended and use the ${var.myvariable}.
